# JQuery Dropzone options not working issue

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I have created a dropzone file upload.My html code is

```
<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" id="myDropzone"></form>
```

And options are

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
        dictDefaultMessage: "Select photos",
        paramName: "file",
        maxFilesize: 0.5,
        clickable: false,
        renameFile: function (file) {
              return file.name = new Date().getTime() + '_' + file.name;
        }
};
});
```

But the options are not working.I am new to dropzone.How can i do this

Comment: Have you checked your console tab (Developer Tools, for Chrome press F12) to see if there any error is reported ?

Comment: @Christos I checked.No errors found

Answer (score 1):

**https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-varahamihira-cci6y**

It's easier to create an instance of Dropzone than trying to use "auto discover" feature.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Prevent Dropzone from auto discovering this element:
  Dropzone.options.myDropzone = false;
  // This is useful when you want to create the
  // Dropzone programmatically later

  // Disable auto discover for all elements:
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

  var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#myDropzone", {
    url: "upload.php",
    dictDefaultMessage: "Select photos",
    paramName: "file",
    maxFilesize: 0.5,
    clickable: false,
    renameFile: function(file) {
      return new Date().getTime() + "_" + file.name;
    }
  });

  myDropzone.on("complete", function(file) {
    console.log(file);
  });
});
```